# How change order of categorial values in PySpark

Tags: pyspark

Let say I have PySpark dataframe

```
+---+----+
|id|value|
+---+---+
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 |
+---+---+
```

The "value" field has 3 unique values (1, 2, 3).

I need to reverse these values in data frame and have the following table

```
+---+----+
|id|value|
+---+---+
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
+---+---+
```

How I can do this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

what about
`df.withColumn("value", 4 - df.value)` ?